# Read different csv file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 csv files in the same storage location directory.

1st csv File:

```
id name age
1  Hi   20
2  Hello 21
```

2nd csv File:

```
id name age country
3  hi1  20   India
```

When I read through spark

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("inferschema","true").load("<location>")
```

I can see all the data and for id 1 and 2 the country is NULL, but I am getting both the headers.

Current Output:

```
_c0 | _c1 | _c2 | _c3 | _c4
id   |name  |country| age | lastname
3    |dfg   |US     | 45  | HI
4    |ghj   |US1    | 33  | Hello
id   | name |country|age  | null
1    |asd   | India |21   | null
2    |sdf   |Australia|20 | null
```

How to get the dataframe with all the column as header and corresponding data in spark.

Expected Output:

```
id   |name  |country| age | lastname
3    |dfg   |US     | 45  | HI
4    |ghj   |US1    | 33  | Hello
1    |asd   | India |21   | null
2    |sdf   |Australia|20 | null
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're aiming at. Can you please add the current and the expected outputs?

Comment: Updated the query

Comment: add the option of header is equal to true like .option("header","true")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell spark that you have headers in the csv files that you are reading by specifying an option of header is true.

You can read your csv files within the folder as below :

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferschema","true").option("header","true").load("<location>")
```

You can see the output as below:

[image]